# Why JSON.stringify($('#calendar').fullcalendar('clientEvents')) fails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, fullcalendar

As title, when I try to do:

```
myString = JSON.stringify($('#calendar').fullcalendar('clientEvents'));
```

it fails. I tried to alert `myString` but I see a series of `[Object object], ... .` But if i try to alert `myArray[0].title` for example, it returns correctly.

Where I'm doing wrong?

P.S. The goal is to obtain a string to save on a file via AJAX.

Comment: *"both example fails"* Both examples are doing the same thing. The array you create in the first line of the second example is thrown away by the assignment in the second line.

Comment: It was a redundancy, sorry.

Comment: Now you're referring to something in the question that you haven't shown (`myArray`). In any case, can you create a [mcve] demonstrating the problem? The [api docs](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/clientEvents/) suggest that method returns an array of objects, I'd expect `JSON.stringify` to process them unless they define a weird `toJSON`.

Comment: Definitely going to need a [mcve]. If I go to http://fullcalendar.io/ and open the console and do `jQuery("#calendar").fullCalendar("clientEvents")` (note the capital `C`) I get an array of events. If I do `JSON.stringify(jQuery("#calendar").fullCalendar("clientEvents"))`, I get `TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON(…)`, which isn't what you say you get.

Comment: What string in your object are you trying to obtain? As for now, you're trying for test purposes to alert a stringified object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your results tell you that the objects in the array that the `fullCalendar` `clientEvents` method gives you can't be directly converted to JSON. I get slightly different results on the http://fullcalendar.io page (I get an error about trying to convert a circular structure); I assume that's down to differences either in the FullCalendar version you're using vs. they're using, or differences in how your browser and mine deal with circular structures. Either way, the objects apparently can't be used as-is.

> The goal is to obtain a string to save on a file via AJAX.

You can do that by using `map` on the array to get objects that *can* be converted to JSON successfully, whitelisting the properties you want (or blacklisting the ones you don't want).

Here's an example whitelisting the `start`, `end`, and `title` properties:

```
var json = JSON.stringify($("#calendar").fullCalendar("clientEvents").map(function(e) {
    return {
        start: e.start,
        end: e.end,
        title: e.title
    };
}));
```

Heres one blacklisting `source` and any property starting with `_`:

```
var json = JSON.stringify($("#calendar").fullCalendar("clientEvents").map(function(e) {
    var rv = {};
    Object.keys(e)
        .filter(function(k) {
            return k != "source" && !k.startsWith("_");
         })
        .forEach(function(k) {
            rv[k] = e[k];
        });
    return rv;
}));
```

...which worked for me on their site.

Here are ES2015 versions of both of those:

Whitelisting:

```
let json = JSON.stringify($("#calendar").fullCalendar("clientEvents").map(e => ({
    start: e.start,
    end: e.end,
    title: e.title
})));
```

Blacklisting:

```
let json = JSON.stringify($("#calendar").fullCalendar("clientEvents").map(e => {
    let rv = {};
    Object.keys(e)
        .filter(k => k != "source" && !k.startsWith("_"))
        .forEach(k => {
            rv[k] = e[k];
        });
    return rv;
}));
```

Comment: This solved my problem, thank you very very much! :)